# long file minus short file equal new file iterating through each line

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

I am trying to bash script this and it seems I am asking the question wrong or can't find a refined example.

I am taking two files that have lists.

`file1`:

```
aa
bb
cc
dd
ee
ff
```

`file2`:

```
bb
dd
ff
```

Create `file3` = `file1` lines - (matching lines in `file2`, at any point in `file1`)

`file3`:

```
aa
cc
ee
```

Thanks for any help or direction.

Answer (score 3):

how about

```
 fgrep -v -f file2 file1
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is ok to resort the files, you can use this:

```
comm -2 -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

I think an eloquent way to describe what you want is the relative complement or set difference. In fact, the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_%28set_theory%29#Complements_in_various_programming_languages) for complment has code examples in many languages, including my solution above, sans the inline sort.

Comment: Apologies for the late response. I tried this last week and ended up with a file that has more lines in it. So I tried it both ways `comm -2 -3 <(sort smallfile) <(sort largefile)` and `comm -2 -3 <(sort largefile) <(sort smallfile)` Neither gave me the results that I was expecting. I will attempt again using the wiki today. Thanks

Comment: I have to say that if this doesn't work for you then maybe I don't understand what you are asking for.  I'm pretty close to 100% sure it does compute the set difference of two files.

Answer (score 1):

If every line from `file2` occurs in `file1` it's rather easy:

```
 sort file1 file2 | uniq -u
```

If the files can not be sorted and you don't know if the above condition is true (about every line), `awk` can do it like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN { while ((getline line < "file2" > 0) {
                   f2[line]++
             }
           }
     f2[$0] > 0 { print }' file1
```

*Note*: I would not use it with really large `file2`.

Comment: really large? my list have up too 22K lines, file size is only 418KB.

Comment: I attempted the sort, and some how end up with more lines in the file3. I need file1-file2 basically. yes all lines in file2 should be in file1. thanks for your time.